# Action on Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="VVP_OpportunityController"  lightningStylesheets="True" action="{!OppRedirect}">



public PageReference OppRedirect(){
    if(oppRed.RecordTypeId == '0121w00000017YWAAY'){
        PageReference parque = new PageReference('/apex/VVP_OpportunityDetailNew');                                                   
        return parque;
    }else{  
        PageReference smartPricing = new PageReference('/006/e?retURL=%2F'+oppRed.AccountId+'&RecordType='+oppRed.RecordTypeId+'&ent=Opportunity&nooverride=1');
        return smartPricing;
    }
}
```

And i want to my Visualforce Page open the correct PageReference, the else condition is working fine. In the if Condition i'm retrive the following error:

**Cyclical server-side forwards detected: /apex/VVP_OpportunityDetailNew**

Can someone help me?

Comment: This occurs when you return the pagereference from apex of a page that you are already on. What page is the apex you posted associated with?

Comment: New standard button, i want that after i press new button i want that de visualforce page or open in the Visualforce page that i'm standing or open the standard menu of new

Comment: Is the button on standard page layout or on a VF Page?

Comment: try setting `parque.setRedirect(true)` in if clause.

Comment: In a Standard page layout

Comment: I'm redirect not tu my visualforce page if i put parque.setRedirect(true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to action on the page, your page is being redirected itself infinite times. If you don't want to redirect your page,

Below code is the problem here.

```
if(oppRed.RecordTypeId == '0121w00000017YWAAY'){
    PageReference parque = new PageReference('/apex/VVP_OpportunityDetailNew');                                                   
    return parque;
}
```

Just replace that with this:

```
if(oppRed.RecordTypeId == '0121w00000017YWAAY'){                                                   
    return null;
}
```

So you will stay on the same page.

Also,

> Do not hard code Ids in your code.

You can get record type id by its name using the below code.

```
Id devRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.ObjectApiName.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('RecordTypeName').getRecordTypeId();
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your page goes into infinite loop. Try putting parameter to your PageReference variable as below:

```
parque.getParameters().put('nooverride', '1');
```

Comment: Show the same error

Comment: Does one of your condition returns the user to same page?